# Is there mechanism for constant pointer to pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, constants, pointer-to-pointer

I wonder does C/C++ allow one to use "const int **" in function call?

Suppose I have a matrix, which can be accessed by pointer to pointer. When I want to use this matrix, and forbid modification of any value in this matrix, can I do "func(const int **mat)"? I have tried this, but when I do something like this "a = mat[0][0]", there is error message.

I wonder if it is allowed to use "const int **" or what is the correct way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1143272/4107809

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: There is a helpful website for the type definitions: http://cdecl.org/. Try inputting `int ** const var`.

Comment: I suspect  your problem is not the type you're passing. Am I correct in assuming `a = mat[0][0]` is called inside `func`'s function body? Also, what are you passing to `func` - how is it declared and initialised?

Answer (score 1):

`const` modifier binds to the token to the left of it. If it is placed all to the left, it is moved one place to the right. So when you write `const int **`, it means `int const **`: the integer finally pointed to is constant, but the pointer may be manipulated. This is probably *exactly* what you want.

So if you are getting an error, it is probably because your `a` doesn't refer to an `int const` (or -- `const int`), but just an `int`.

Comment: But what you want to achieve is that the `mat[0][0]` is constant but that `a` can be assigned to. So assigning a const to an int is fine, but assigning an int to a const is flagged,